# Routing does not work propley in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am have problems with routing in Laravel 8 This is my web.php file

```
use App\Http\Controllers\AlbumsController;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
//Route::get('/', function () {
  //  return view('welcome');
//});


Route::get('/', [AlbumsController::class,'index']);
```

This works, however, the index.blade.php file is in resources/views/albums/. If I do:

```
Route::get('/albums', [AlbumsController::class,'index']);
```

I get a Object not found error.

My Controller is

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AlbumsController extends Controller
{
  public function index(){
      return view('albums.index');
    }
 {
```

At the moment there is nothing in the index.blade.php file except the word Index, I am checking if the routes work.

Your help is appreciated

Comment: Can you add exact error message to your question so we can see where is the source fie of error?

Comment: I am not getting any error messages. Only what I stated above. Unless I am not looking in the right places. Where would that be?. I have looked at the laravel.log. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to the above question. What I did was changed:
These routes from

`Route::get('/albums/create', ('AlbumsController@create')`

`Route::get('/albums/index', ('AlbumsController@index')`

to

```
Route::get('/', ('AlbumsController@create')
```

Strange as this is, it works!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it’s because You didn’t close properly the curly brackets of your AlbumsController class.
Try this instead :

```php
class AlbumsController extends Controller
{
  public function index(){
      return view('albums.index');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out unfortunatley did not make any difference

Comment: try to comment the return method and echo something to see if it's working or not.